# app engine: no api in explorer

Tags: android, google-app-engine, endpoints

I'm trying to use the Google Plugin to create a Web API as shown in this video:

[Building web API's for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dylFNrvZ_3U#!/)
seen from 26:50 until 39:40

I need a database for my Android app and try to use Google cloud endpoints, but am unable to do it following this video. I've been searching for more than a day on figuring out what I am doing wrong.

When I run the web application,

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=message
```

look alright and I can insert data using curl

for instance:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d ' { "msMsg" : "my message!", "id" : 1 } ' http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/msgendpoint/v1/msg
```

But when I do

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer
```

I get this:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /_ah/api/explorer. Reason:
     NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Endpoints are currently under a trusted testers closed program. Have you applied? http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com

Comment: Thanks! That is in deed the case, I am not accepted yet. I wasn't sure that I would not be able to use it locally...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to deploy your app to get this URL to work. As an alternative, you can try navigating to a URL like this:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8888/_ah/api

This URL will read your local Discovery document (from your browser) and display the APIs Explorer for those APIs.

Comment: No, too bad. This does the explorer screen with the 'Services', 'all versions' and 'request history' options on the left, but the center frame of the page stays empty. Am I misconfiguring it somehow? I have no experience whatsoever with this. BTW: I also already deployed it, but that doesn't work either...I am missing something...

Comment: Can you point me to your deployed API? I can diagnose this better with that information, it may be a bug in Endpoints.

Comment: I've send an e-mail to your gmail account I found somewhere. Not sure if it could do any damage if the url is publicly displayed. I'm really new at app engine.

Comment: @JasonHall On this topic, I ask, I have already signed up for trusted tester program but till it is being considered, How am I suppose to consume my endpoints locally or should I sit and wait and hold back my development till then?

Comment: Resolved it by now? Just tried this and it worked for me. But Endpoints is out of TT by now..